# Insert or delete rows from a table according to a field in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a very complex question. Can anyone give me any directions for the following scenario,

I have two tables. tblone, tbltwo. I want to insert or delete records in tbltwo according to the Quantity value in tblone. For example If the tbl.Quantity is 4 and I have 2 rows in tbltwo, then I need to add two rows. If the tbl.Quantity is 1 and tbltwo has 3 rows I want to delete 2 rows. I'm really confused. Any help is appreciated. I tried with a cursor but no success.

```
SELECT Quantity
FROM tblOrder
WHERE visitid = 123123
```

result is 4

```
SELECT count(Product)
FROM tblProducts
WHERE visitid = 123123
```

result is 2

So I want to add two rows from tblTwo for the visitId = 123123

tblShipment

```
VisitID|Quantity|Type
12313      4     cotton
```

tblProducts

```
ProductID|type  |method|
 2222     cotton  first
 2223     cotton  first
```

Expected result:

```
ProductID|type  |method|
 2222     cotton  first
 2223     cotton  first
 2224     cotton  first
 2225     cotton  first
```

I hope this make sense, I want to add or delete rows according to the Quantity value

Comment: Showing data and what criteria decides on deletions would help. I hope. Also, show what you have tried.

Comment: So it looks like the `Quantity` in `tblone` will determine how many rows should be in `tbltwo`. Is that correct?

Comment: [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) is the [SAK](http://www.sakwiki.com/tiki-index.php) of statements. It can also be the Regular Expression of TSQL: now you have two problems.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thats correct

Comment: Why do you want to have a bunch of duplicate data in your database in the first place? You could just join to a tally/numbers table when you read the data and you don't need to store a number of rows like this.

Comment: You really need to name your tables more to what they are actually for. Next time you ask a question here and say "I'm having a problem with tbl234564 and tbl678854", no one is going to have a clue of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Chuck Sorry. I just updated more sensible table names

Comment: If you will add the rows, What data they will contain? I think this can easily be done by using Temp tables but will help us more to answer if sample data posted.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I updated the question with some sample data. Thanks a lot

Comment: @KMR Addition of product id is sequence or it is getting derived from another table? When you will delete a row, first row should get deleted or the last one?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Product Id is a sequence and when deleting, the first row gets deleted. Thanks a lot

Comment: If your ProductID is an Identity (Identity Specification=Yes) then it will auto increment and you would only need to insert the two new records?

Comment: @Chuck this is the only trick of this question.

Comment: @Chuck Do you have an example. I'm still confused how I'm going to do the insert according to the quantity as quantity can change

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and let me know if you face any issues there

```
begin

  DECLARE @visitid INTEGER;
  DECLARE @quantity INTEGER;
  DECLARE @type VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE @productid INTEGER;
  DECLARE @method VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE @diff NUMERIC;
  DECLARE @CNT INTEGER;

 with temp as 
 (
  select type,count(1) as cnt 
  from tblproducts
  group by type
 )
select s.visitid,s.quantity,s.type,p.productid,p.method,temp.cnt as cnt  
 into #tempor
from tblshipment s join tblproducts p
on s.type=p.type 
inner join temp on 
s.type=temp.type 
and s.quantity <> temp.cnt 

declare productcursor cursor for select 
visitid,quantity,type,productid,method,cnt 
from #tempor 

open productcursor

 fetch next from productcursor into 
 @visitid,@quantity,@type,@productid,@method,@cnt

while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
 BEGIN 
   declare @i integer;
  set @i=1;
 if (@Quantity-@cnt) > 0 
  BEGIN
       while (@i < (@Quantity-@cnt) ) 
       BEGIN 
           insert into tblproducts SELECT max(productid) + 1 AS 
           PRODCUTID,type AS TYPE,method AS METHOD
           from tblproducts t 
           where type=@type and method=@method group by type,method 

          SET @i = @i+1;   
        END     
       fetch next from productcursor into 
    @visitid,@quantity,@type,@productid,@method,@cnt ;
   END 
  ELSE IF (@quantity-@cnt) <0 
   BEGIN
        while (@i <= (@cnt-@quantity))
       BEGIN             
           select *,
           row_number() over(partition by type,method order by productid 
            desc) as rn 
           into #del
           from tblproducts     

           delete from tblproducts 
           where productid in (select productid from #del where rn <=(@cnt-
            @quantity))
           and type=@type and method=@method
           SET @i = @i+1; 
        END
        fetch next from productcursor into 
        @visitid,@quantity,@type,@productid,@method,@cnt ;
     END
  END   

  close productcursor
  deallocate productcursor ;
 END
```

Comment: If Productid is an identity column then please do the changes to reflect that by removing the productid from the insert